# can't get correct plot from alpha vantage and plotly

Tags: plotly

I am trying to plot a week stock data from alpha vantage with `plotly` but I get weird plots compared to other source's plot like google's chart for example.

```
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='MSFT',interval='1min', outputsize='full')
data = data.sort_index()
```

If I plot without the x axis labels, I get a correct plot but the x labels are replaced with integer ranges.

```
close_graph = go.Scatter(y=data['4. close'], hoverinfo=['y'])
close_layout = go.Layout(title='Intraday Times Series for the MSFT stock (1 min)')
close_fig = go.Figure(data=close_graph, layout=close_layout)
```

[image: plot without explicit x axis]

else if I do something like

```
close_graph = go.Scatter(y=data['4. close'], x=data.index, hoverinfo=['y'])
```

I get a weird plot

[image: plot with x axis labels]